# d3.js: show hour,minutes,seconds,miliseconds on x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have date format in iso date format "2013-07-20T17:01:30.500Z" and i want to plot hours,minutes and seconds on x axis .

```
var minDate = d3.min(dataset, function(d) {

            return d.timestamp;
        });
        var maxDate = d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
            return d.timestamp;
        });
```

dataset is a json array which has all entries.

```
       var x = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, w]);

       var xScale = d3.time.scale().domain([minDate, maxDate]).range([0, w]);
```

I am using following code to create x axis in graph.

```
  var format = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S.%LZ");
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickFormat(format);
```

It is giving me error "Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,"

http://jsfiddle.net/priya78/Q9W4J/

Answer (score -1):

You need to parse the dates before sending them to the scale:

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(dataset.map(format.parse))
    .range([0, w]);
```

Since you'll need to use the parsed dates repeated, generally it is a good idea to modify your `data` before you do anything else with it:

```
dataset.forEach(function(d){ d.timestamp = format.parse(d.timestamp); })
```

EDIT: Your [format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#wiki-format_iso) is also incorrect, try:

```
d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ")
```

[fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q9W4J/2/)

Comment: it is returning null dataset.forEach(function(d){ d.time = format.parse(d.timestamp); }) every time

Comment: but i want to show only hours,minutes,seconds,miliseconds on x axis

Comment: can u please provide me example of that?